# Vim for editing confidential files

Tags: vim

I often use /usr/bin/vim to edit normal files. When editing /etc/sudoers, "visudo" seems a good way. And when editing /etc/group, using "vigr" is popular. This is probably because they check syntax automatically and prevent any problems from happening.
Are there any other commands which allows me to re-write important files safely?

Comment: Thanks! When do I need to edit /etc/passwd?

Comment: `sudoedit` will invoke whatever `EDITOR` is set to, which for me is `vim`